# Is it possible to add file to multiple git repos at the same time?

Tags: android, git, actionbarsherlock

I have been working on Android applications for a while now. One problem I faced quite often is that new people have trouble keeping up with all the dependency of library projects. Things went from bad to worse with my latest project, which we use 7 libraries (2 developed in-house and a lot of open-sources). Right now we are using both Bitbucket and Github for our solution.

Is it possible to just combine all the projects under one Git repo? So we can just clone one and start working right away while maintaining the connection to the original repo of those open-source project.

For instance, it uses ActionBarSherlock, FacebookSDK, SlideMenu, etc.

If not, would Maven solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) are the solution to this problem.

You would add the repositories of those libraries as submodules to the repository of your app.

Comment: This looks like what I needed. Look a bit complicated to Git beginner like me tho.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assumed you have your 'main' project already setup and your local reg setup, and EGit.

1. Eclipse->rightclick on library project -> Team -> SharePrject-> git-> set Reg as the one your main is contained. If its a lib, then I suggest leave 'Path within reg' alone. ->finish.
2. You will get a bunch of errors. This is because the physcial location of the project has moved to the reg. Fix dependencies->Relink libraries( ex support-v4) -> readd library projects-> commit.

And of course don't forget to back up before doing anything.

Comment: Does this means we have to do it on every one PC? I'm using IntelliJ while my coworker is using Eclipse at the moment.

Comment: Once its in the remote repo then just have the others pull from it. Its a one-time setup.